# Area of a scalene trapezoid inscribed in a rectangle between right triangles

Tags: geometry

I have a scalene trapezoid/trapezium with a longer base that is double the length of shorter base. I add to the trapezoid two right triangles so that I create a rectangle with the same height of the trapezoid and a base that coincides with longer base of the trapezoid. If the sum of the areas of the two triangles is 20 cm^2 together, what is the area of the trapezoid?

Answer (score 0):

Given scalene trapezoid ABDC, with $AB=2CD$, and rectangle $ABFE$ in which $$\triangle AEC+\triangle DFB=20\mathrm cm^2$$ first complete parallelogram $ABDG$.

Since $EC+DF=CD$, and $GE=DF$, then $GC=CD=\frac{AB}{2}$, and $\triangle AGC=\triangle AEC+\triangle DFB=20\mathrm cm^2$
[image: area of scalene trapezoid]
Now bisect $AB$ at $H$ and join $CH$, $DH$.

Since parallelograms$$GCHA=CDHA=CDBH$$then$$\triangle ACH=\triangle CDH=\triangle HDB=\triangle AGC=20\mathrm cm^2$$and trapezoid$$ABDC=3\cdot20=60\mathrm cm^2$$